# How to display a ng2-chart with Angular 2 on dropdown menu click?

Tags: javascript, angular, document, innerhtml, ng2-charts

I want that if the user presses a button , a chart to show op on the page. I want to write this html into innerHTML:

```
<div style="display: block">
<canvas baseChart
      [datasets]="barChartData"
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [chartType]="barChartType"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"></canvas>
</div>
```

I tried to copy it like this but the chart doesnt show op. I think it doesnt read the properties well.

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = " <div style=\"display: block\">\n" +
  "  <canvas baseChart\n" +
  "          [datasets]=\"barChartData\"\n" +
  "          [labels]=\"barChartLabels\"\n" +
  "          [options]=\"barChartOptions\"\n" +
  "          [chartType]=\"barChartType\"\n" +
  "          [legend]=\"barChartLegend\"></canvas>\n" +
  "</div>  some text <br>\n" +
  "  some more text: <strong> "+ this.item + "</strong><br>\n" +
  "\n" +
  "  some more text:  <br>\n" +
  "  Monday: <strong> " + this.percentMonday + "%</strong>  <br>\n"
```

However when I put it in html file it shows up properly. 
How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

```
   div class="dropdown" dropdown [dropdownToggle]="false">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-open>Kies een stad voor meer info</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li value="Amsterdam" (click)="goToAmsterdam()"><a>Amsterdam</a></li>



  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Which libraries are you using? It looks like `baseChart` is an external script which executes a command as soon as any HTML tag contains that phrase.

Comment: I am using ng2-charts

Comment: (using Angular )

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The inserted HTML code won't be converted/compiled and treated as an ordinary string. Try maybe this line of code, that I will post in a few seconds.

Comment: Is it completly neccessary to use `innerHTML`?

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT no it not. I just want to show the corresponding chart whenever the user chooses a value from a dropdown menu. I will add that menu to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163711/discussion-between-nextlevelshit-and-user3660293).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easily, if your are not neccessarily have to use `innerHTML`: Firstly, do not use native JavaScript, if you are using Angular(2). Secondly, just add this lines to your code.

JS inside your corresponding Controller:

```
//...
export class YOURCOMPONENT implements OnInit {
  showChart: boolean; // store toggle state of the chart

  constructor () { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showChart = false; // hide chart at the beginning
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="showChart">
    <canvas baseChart
      [datasets]="barChartData"
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [chartType]="barChartType"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"></canvas>
</div>
<button (click)="showChart=!showChart">Toggle Chart</button>
```

`(click)="showChart=!showChart"` means that on clicking the button the value of `showChart` will swap from true to false and vice versa.